# How can I use a condition in PDO object while a query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to Select Data With PDO (+ Prepared Statements)
The following example uses prepared statements.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_pdo

I need to know how to make a condition to display only the LASTNAME = PETER.  I tried like the below, but not working

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname =PETER");
```

Comment: `lastname ='PETER'` enclose `peter` with single quotes

Comment: For such type use `PDO::query` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: I tried lastname ='PETER' but not working

Comment: Did you do a `$stmt->execute()` after `$stmt = $conn->prepare()`?

Comment: Just follow the PHP PDO Syntax http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prepare and execute use like this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = :lastname");
$result = $stmt->execute(array(':lastname'=>'PETER'));
```

And if you want to run directly (which is not recommended if 'PETER' is coming from an user input).

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = 'PETER');
```

Comment: small typo `$stmt =`/`$stmnt->`

Comment: @Sean, Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The condition being handed to the `WHERE` clause needs to be single quoted as it is (I presume) a string. So:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = 'PETER'");
```

Remember if you are going to make this dynamic in future to sanitise your inputs and use some kind of named parameters like so:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests WHERE lastname = :lastname");
$stmt->execute([':lastname' => 'PETER']); // the string here can be a variable of course
```